# What's the dimension of the Lie algebra generated by transpositions on $n$ objects?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-algebras, permutations, catalan-numbers

Define a Lie bracket on the group algebra of the permutation group $S_n$ in the following way:
$$[\sigma, \tau] = \sigma\circ\tau - \tau\circ\sigma,$$
where $\sigma, \tau \in S_n$, and the multiplication on permutations is defined as composition. My question is, what is the dimension of the Lie subalgebra generated by transpositions, i.e. $(ij)$? My conjecture is that the dimension is given by $C_n - \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, where $C_n$ is the Catalan number. Is this correct and what is the proof?

For example, when $n=3$, using the cycle notation, we have
$$
[(12),(23)] = (132) - (123) \\
[(23),(31)] = (132) - (123) \\
[(31),(12)] = (132) - (123) \\
$$
and
$$
[(12), (132) - (123)] = 2((23) - (13)), \text{etc.}
$$
Therefore this algebra is $4 = C_3 - 1$ dimensional.

If this conjecture is correct, the result should not be hard to generalize to the Lie subalgebras generated by $S_k$ for $k<n$, which should be related to [A214015](https://oeis.org/A214015) and [A026820](https://oeis.org/A026820).

Update: As pointed in the comment, this conjecture is wrong. It fails from $n=6$, where there is an unexpected $\mathfrak{so}(16)$ piece in the Lie algebra.

Comment: Dimension is what you say for $n=4$ and $n=5$, however for $n=6$ it is $249$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Would you like to describe how you get the result? I expected that the number I suggested should at least be an upper bound.

Comment: I used `GAP`: first `tr:=List(Combinations([1..6],2),p->(p[1],p[2]));` then `G:=Group(tr);` then `A:=GroupRing(Rationals,G);` then `emb:=Embedding(G,A);` then `L:=LieAlgebra(A);` then `S:=Subalgebra(L,List(tr,x->LieObject(emb(x))));` and finally `Dimension(S);`

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks a lot! I just got `GAP` installed and verified your result. Everything works fine except that I need to change `emb(x)` to `Image(emb,x)`, presumably due to different versions. This is really unexpected! Do you think using a group algebra over rationals instead of over complex numbers will make any difference?

Comment: My `GAP` is 4.12. In the meanwhile I calculated the structure a bit. For $n\leqslant6$ the algebra has 1-dimensional center spanned by the sum of all transpositions. The rest is semisimple for $n<6$: $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ for $n=3$, $\mathfrak{sl}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ for $n=4$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(4)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(5)$ for $n=5$. Unfortunately it is still struggling determining the structure for $n=6$.

Comment: As for the base field, I am sure it does not matter. Tensoring with complexes would not change dimension of a vector space.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Mine is 4.11, just downloaded from their website. Your result coincides with mine, but I am a little bit curious how you did the calculation. I thought this algebra was isomorphic to the centralizer of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ represented on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$, and this is where the conjecture comes from. Now it seems that this is only true for $n<6$, while for $n=6$, the centralizer is $\mathfrak{sl}(5)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(9)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(5)$.

Comment: I just ask about `LieCenter(S);` and `SemiSimpleType(LieDerivedSubalgebra(S));` assuming that it is reductive (which it turns out to be: if it would not be the case, `GAP` would fail on determining the semisimple type). Mine is finally done with the structure, it is $\mathfrak{sl}(5)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(9)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(5)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(16)$ (plus 1-dimensional center).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Wow, `GAP` is so powerful!

Comment: The following paper (in french) gives an explicit description of this Lie algebra (see Theorem A) : I. Marin, L'algèbre de Lie des transpositions ( arXiv:math/0502119).

Comment: @Adrien you should post this as an answer. Now it is hidden behind the 'show 11 more comments' button

Comment: @Vincent good point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In "L'algèbre de Lie des transpositions" ([arXiv:math/0502119](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502119)
), Ivan Marin shows the Lie algebra generated by transpositions is the product of a 1 dimensional Lie algebra, and of a semi-simple Lie algebra, and provides an explicit decomposition of the latter as a direct sum of special linear, symplectic and orthogonal Lie algebras. See theorem A and section 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the result I need.